# Building OpenSSL 1.0.2n for 64-bit Android with NDK r16b undefined reference to bsd_signal

Tags: android, android-ndk, openssl

I'm trying to get OpenSSL 1.0.2n to build using the latest Android NDK r16b. Building for 32-bit archs (armv7, x86) works just fine, but when I try building for 64-bit archs (arm64, x86_64) I get a linker error stating that bsd_signal is undefined:

```
shlib_target=; if [ -n "libcrypto.so.1.0.0 libssl.so.1.0.0" ]; then \
        shlib_target="linux-shared"; \
    elif [ -n "" ]; then \
      FIPSLD_CC="aarch64-linux-android-gcc"; CC=/usr/local/ssl/fips-2.0/bin/fipsld; export CC FIPSLD_CC; \
    fi; \
    LIBRARIES="-L.. -lssl  -L.. -lcrypto" ; \
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -f ../Makefile.shared -e \
        APPNAME=openssl OBJECTS="openssl.o verify.o asn1pars.o req.o dgst.o dh.o dhparam.o enc.o passwd.o gendh.o errstr.o ca.o pkcs7.o crl2p7.o crl.o rsa.o rsautl.o dsa.o dsaparam.o ec.o ecparam.o x509.o genrsa.o gendsa.o genpkey.o s_server.o s_client.o speed.o s_time.o apps.o s_cb.o s_socket.o app_rand.o version.o sess_id.o ciphers.o nseq.o pkcs12.o pkcs8.o pkey.o pkeyparam.o pkeyutl.o spkac.o smime.o cms.o rand.o engine.o ocsp.o prime.o ts.o srp.o" \
        LIBDEPS=" $LIBRARIES -ldl" \
        link_app.${shlib_target}
req.o: In function `req_main':
req.c:(.text+0x368): undefined reference to `bsd_signal'
ca.o: In function `ca_main':
ca.c:(.text+0xe90): undefined reference to `bsd_signal'
ecparam.o: In function `ecparam_main':
ecparam.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `bsd_signal'
s_server.o: In function `s_server_main':
s_server.c:(.text+0x32c0): undefined reference to `bsd_signal'
pkcs12.o: In function `pkcs12_main':
pkcs12.c:(.text+0x1134): undefined reference to `bsd_signal'
cms.o:cms.c:(.text+0x98): more undefined references to `bsd_signal' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I saw that `bsd_signal` had been omitted from NDK at one point, but it was added back in NDK 13 (https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/160). Besides, if it were missing entirely I would expect the 32-bit builds to fail as well.

Here are the configurations I'm attempting to use for the arm64 build (this is actually done with a script, which is quite long. To avoid pasting the whole nonsense here, these are the values that wind up being used when it is executed):

```
export MACHINE=armv7
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE="aarch64-linux-android-"
export ANDROID_SYSROOT="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64"
export SYSROOT="$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export NDK_SYSROOT="$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT="$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export ANDROID_API=android-21

export ANDROID_DEV="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr"
export HOSTCC=gcc
export ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin"
export PATH="$ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN":"$PATH"

./Configure shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp no-hw no-engine linux-generic64 --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl/android-21 -fPIE -D__ANDROID_API__=android-21 -I$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sysroot/usr/include -I$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -B$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/lib

make clean
make CALC_VERSIONS="SHLIB_COMPAT=; SHLIB_SOVER=" depend
make CALC_VERSIONS="SHLIB_COMPAT=; SHLIB_SOVER=" all
```

I've tried so many different things at this point I couldn't even begin to list them.

Anyone see what I'm missing here?

Comment: In the test case commit [there's a function called `match_unsupported`](https://github.com/pombredanne/android.googlesource.com-platform-ndk/commit/f37dc81f824c803e08f3c0ec06d8b8ae1ab2b9fc#diff-def7b281a17a430142d7646cb5042599) which appears to match against all 64-bit ABIs. I didn't see any explanation for that in the commit or in the issue though.

Comment: It was not put *back* for LP64 ABIs because the function call has never existed on the LP64 ABIs. Adding it to the NDK stub libs would let you build, but you'd just crash when the library loads since there's no implementation on the device :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would recommend to use the **make** that is shipped with Android NDK to build with NDK toolchain. If it's not on your PATH, you'll find it at

   ```
   $ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/make
   ```

   I don't think this is a real cause of your problem here.
2. **bsd_signal** is exported from `platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib/libc.so`, and also the corresponding `libc.a`, but not from `platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/usr/lib/libc.so`.
3. It is marked as **`__REMOVED_IN(21)`** in the unified headers, so I would expect the compiler to issue a warning about using an undefined function.
4. A possible workaround is to provide a dummy `bsd_signal`, as *Felipe Cavalcanti* proposed [on GitHub](https://github.com/felipejfc/openssl_prebuilt_for_android).
5. The issue with **bsd_signal** seems to have been resolved in openssl 1.1 series.
6. You have a mistake on command line: use **`-D__ANDROID_API__=21`** instead.

Comment: Sadly none of that worked. Adding the phony `bsd_signal` implementation shown in the GitHub repo you linked to just wound up causing other weird problems, and switching to OpenSSL 1.1 still has the `bsd_signal` link error (although slightly different). Looking at OpenSSL's GitHub project, they have an open item for 1.1.1 to add arm64 support though (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/2490). Guess I'll just have to wait.

Comment: Which weird problems do you see with the phony `bsd_signal`? Actually, your command line has a mistake that I didn't notice yesterday, see updated answer.

Comment: Note that it's safer to use static libs, not shared libs for libssl and libcrypto: on older platforms (like android-21), dynamic linker may pick up the copies from `/system/lib`, which may result in weird problems.

Comment: Thanks! The edit (#6) got things working. Stubbing in the phony `bsd_signal` caused it to be unable to locate certain headers, other different linker errors, and lots of other weird stuff. I added it to `apps.c`, so maybe something with that, but IDK - I didn't bother chasing it much. Also, I actually _do_ use the static libs for my project for this very reason. The `shared` flag is just a left over artifact from the original script source.

Comment: Yes, without a valid __ANDROID_API__ the unified headers of NDK r16 cannot work correctly

Comment: Yeah, I ran into that when I first started trying to use NDK r16 to build for armv7a, but for whatever reason passing `-D__ANDROID_API__=android-19` worked - no idea why. Seems like it shouldn't have.

Comment: Also of important note - you _have_ to pass the `shared` option when configuring OpenSSL if you're building for x86 or x86_64, otherwise `-fPIC` won't get passed as the first parameter to the compiler & you'll get linker errors when you try to link agains the library.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like a case of building against one API level and linking against another (or perhaps a mismatch of the header ABI vs the library ABI?). To rule out any configuration issues (and to simply your build even if it doesn't solve the issue), I'd recommend using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain).